# Auto scroll on woocommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, autoscroll

i work on a project with woo.
On the mobile version of the site, the cart is a popup window.
When the customer adds many different products he must scroll down to see the buttons "view cart" "pay".

I try to add an autoscroll js code. When someone opens the cart it must scroll down automatically and stops at buttons "view cart" "pay".

I found some codes for "autoscroll to div" but none of them worked for me.

One simple js code i play with is this

```
$('#start').click(function() {
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#bodycontainer').position().top
}, 1000 );});
```

but nothing happened.
Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to scroll the wrong thing, if it is the container that has the scroll. Replace it with this:

```
$('#start').click(function() {
$('#bodycontainer').animate({
   scrollTop: 10000
}, 1000 );});
```

Now if you aren't using a container, then you may wish to add one.

Answer (score 0):

I totally confused

My code for mini-cart is this

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $woocommerce;
?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart' ); ?>

<div class="cart_list <?php echo esc_attr( $args['list_class'] ); ?>">

    <?php if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) : ?>

        <?php
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );


                if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {

                    $product_name  = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    $thumbnail     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    $product_price     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    ?>
                    <div class="media widget-product">

                        <div class="media-left">
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product_permalink ); ?>" class="image pull-left">
                                <?php echo trim($thumbnail); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-main-content media-body">
                            <h3 class="name">
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product_permalink ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo trim($product_name); ?>
                                </a>
                            </h3>
                            <p class="cart-item">
                                <?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); ?>
                                <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', '<span class="quantity">' . sprintf( '%s &times; %s', $cart_item['quantity'], $product_price ) . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
                            </p>

                            <?php
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
                            '<a href="%s" class="remove remove_from_cart_button" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-cart_item_key="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
                                esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                __( 'Remove this item', 'opal_drop' ),
                                esc_attr( $product_id ),
                            esc_attr( $cart_item_key ),
                                esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                            ), $cart_item_key );
                            ?>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
        ?>


    <?php else : ?>

        <div class="empty"><?php esc_html_e( 'No products in the cart.', 'opal_drop' ); ?></div>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div><!-- end product list -->

<?php if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) : ?>

    <p class="total"><strong><?php esc_html_e( 'Subtotal', 'opal_drop' ); ?>:</strong> <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); ?></p>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_before_buttons' ); ?>

    <p class="buttons clearfix">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_cart_url()); ?>" class="btn view-cart btn-default pull-left wc-forward"><?php esc_html_e( 'View Cart', 'opal_drop' ); ?></a>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" class="btn check-out btn-primary text-white pull-right checkout wc-forward"><?php esc_html_e( 'Checkout', 'opal_drop' ); ?></a>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_mini_cart' ); ?>
```

and i try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                    if ( $(window).width() < 768 || window.Touch) { 
                        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#cart-main-content .media-body").offset().top
    }, 2000);
                    } 
});
```

With no luck. Now i practise with jquery